# "the fourth liar in line" / "the fourth most important liar" or something else?

Tags: word-usage

I have to find a title for a story about two inventors, the Short brothers, who ended up writing hundreds of letters, containing lies, to various entrepreneurs, trying to get them to invest money in their projects. Finally they teamed up with one of their physics' teachers who reluctantly started to send fraudulent letters to investors claiming he had witnessed their experiments. At one point, the eccentric William Carbide, got involved in this scam, writing a few articles in a little known magazine with few readers. The story is mainly about this William Carbide who in the end did nothing.

The original title is something like (1) or (2). However, I am not sure if they sound good in English. I am looking for a suitable title that keeps the main idea in (1) or (2).

> (1) William Carbide, **the fourth liar in line** after the Short brothers and their mentor, Dr. Thompson

or

> (2) William Carbide, **the fourth most important liar** after the Short brothers and their mentor, Dr. Thompson

Comment: Do you mean **fourth (4th)**?

Comment: Yes, fourth. I will make the change.

Comment: I suggest: The Fourth Liar in a Row, or Liar Number Four

Answer (score 2):

I like Lambie's suggestion:

> Eventually they recruited the eccentric William Carbide as *Liar Number Four*, who ...

However if you are going to use this it's good writing style to have already established the others, in some way, as Liars One to Three.

> This story is about the Short Brothers, who wrote hundreds of letters to various potential investors, to solicit funding for their nonexistent inventions.  Despite their efforts the two liars were not very successful until they recruited the help of a third liar, their Physics teacher (Name) ...  Eventually they recruited Liar Number Four, William Carbide ...

(As a side note I'm not sure that "entrepreneurs" is the word you want to use in this context.  Usually it means someone who has an entrepreneurial idea of their own and not necessarily someone who invests in others' projects.  Here "investors" or "potential investors" is probably more accurate for the time period.  Nowadays you could also use the term "venture capitalist" instead.)

Comment: So, Lambie and Andrew, from your suggestions I understand that the title should be: "William Carbide, the Liar Number Four After the Short Brothers and Their Mentor, Dr. Thompson"? I am also not sure about "the Liar". Should it be like this or simply "Liar", without article?